# Using emacs (spacemacs) prodigy to run a python app within a virtual env

Tags: python, emacs, virtualenv

I have defined a [prodigy](https://github.com/rejeep/prodigy.el) service with:

```
(prodigy-define-service
  :name "Sproxy"
  :cwd "~/Projects/Python/sproxy"
  :command "python"
  :args '("bin/sproxy" "runserver")
  :tags '(python)
  :init (lambda() (pyvenv-workon "sproxy")))
```

but when I run the service I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "bin/sproxy", line 2, in <module>
      from flask.ext.script import Manager, prompt_bool
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.script
```

The virtualenv does not appear to be activated. I have tried setting the `:env` by hand:

```
:env '(("VIRTUAL_ENV" "~/.virtualenvs/sproxy/")...
```

But that did not work either

Comment: Hi, a suggestion: try calling `pyenv-workon` manually beforehand, so it is activated globally for emacs, and we can be sure it's working and it's a pb with prodigy.

Comment: I want to keep the environment local if possible, unfortunately I have to juggle several projects and virtualenvs

Comment: I understand, it was a suggestion to separate the concerns and see better where your pb comes from. Maybe your prodigy command works fine and you have a pb with how you activate the venv, maybe the venv works fine and you didn't write the prodigy service correctly. When I read your question I don't know where is actually the pb.